# How can i create a custom Poll WebPart in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to create a custom webpart in sharepoint 2010.It should contains the bar/pie chart that shows the result of the poll and it should not allow the user to vote for morethan one time.

Please share any useful link to do this by using VS2010.

Thanks.
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You will get many examples on Codeplex.

http://pollingwebpart.codeplex.com/

http://spuserpoll.codeplex.com/

Comment: i downloaded the webpart from the link 
http://pollingwebpart.codeplex.com/,but while executing the "STSADM –o addsolution –filename c:\pollingwebpart.wsp" in command prompt, i am receiving the error "Acess Denied"..can u please tell me how to solve the problem....i m using sharepoint 2010.